# Issue in encoding percent value

Tags: javascript

I'm encoding a URL string with % value in it.

URL string - Nanoparticles with 70 % Photoluminescence

but it's getting converted to

Nanoparticles%20with%2070%E2%80%89%25%20Photoluminescence and clicking on this is resulting a 404 page.

Could you please let me know how to escape these % values from encoding??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%E2%80%89` is Unicode character THIN SPACE, which means that the space between `70` and `%` is not a normal space (`%20`).

You'll either have to fix the space manually (just delete it and press spacebar), or if you can't do that, you need to replace it with a normal space programmatically before encoding:

```
encodeURI( 'Nanoparticles with 70 % Photoluminescence'.replace( /\u2009/g, ' ' ) );
```